# Why can't I create a temp table twice in a row from SSMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm probably fundamentally misunderstanding temp tables -

But from within SSMS, I have the following:

```
Create Table #temp(FromUserId int, ToUserId int, FromAction int, ToAction int, IsMatch int)
```

If I Execute this twice, I get the error:

```
There is already an object named '#temp' in the database.
```

Why is this happening if the table is #temporary?

Comment: Just because it is temporary doesn't mean that it doesn't exist.  You need to delete it or leave the scope for the table to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temp tables have scope either local to the connection or global to all connections. When I build procedures with temp tables I work in a normal query window and I have a drop statement before each create. Then when it is all set I add the create procedure code and comment out the drop table statements as during normal execution the temp table will not exist yet.   Here is a really good article on the subject of temporary tables.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 5):

Each SSMS tab is its own connection.  Any temp objects you create won't get dropped until you close it or drop it explicitly.  It's actually quite useful behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The temp table will last until it is explicitly dropped or the session that created it ends.
Try closing your query window in SSMS and open a new one.  Your temp table will not be available in the new query window.

Answer (score 0):

I would add that if your procedure or code includes a SELECT INTO #tmp or CREATE TABLE #tmp down the line, you could include the following statement at the beginning of your procedure/query :

```
IF OBJECT_ID(tempDB..#Tmp) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp
```

This will ensure that you can reuse the proc without worrying about trying to create/use a table that already exists.

Comment: Actually, I'm seeing the opposite (in some admittedly dodgy code) - try running this:

````CREATE TABLE #test(Column1 INT); -- these lines are the same

IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test') IS NOT NULL)
 DROP TABLE #test

CREATE TABLE #test(Column1 INT); -- these lines are the same````

Comment: i might be mistaken but in the case of the above code wrapping the DROP TABLE syntax with BEGIN... END or at least a statement terminator might solve it.

Comment: having tried your code on my sandbox, I think the compilation error can be avoided by omitting the 1st line of the statement. the entire batch becomes re-executable after that